# How to get region of an MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to get the region of an MKMapView. Code samples all over the internets show it to be simply mapView.region, but my mapView reference doesn't show it has any properties.

Step 1: 
Create variable on my ViewController (tried this with weak and strong)

```
@property (weak, nonatomic)  MKMapView *tableMapView;
```

Step 2:

Write some code in updateSearchResultsForSearchController to search on a region, but fail horribly with an error.

```
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = self.searchController.searchBar.text;
request.region = self.tableMapView.region <--- "Member reference base type int is not a struct or union."
```

Step 3:

Try to access any properties or methods on my mapview and get nothing.

```
self.tableMapView.nnnnnn
```

UPDATE:

Fixed all RED warnings and now getting this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic)  MKMapView *tableMapView;  <-- property with WEAK attribute must be of type object
```

FIXED:

Fix is to just use nonatomic.

Comment: WFM when pasting this into one of my ViewControllers. Are you sure `self.tableMapView` is defined as you think it is?

Comment: The syntax you’ve shared with us is fine, so your problem rests elsewhere (e.g., a missing or extraneous brace/bracket/parenthesis; some other earlier error; either the property is declared in the wrong place or this code which is trying to access it is, etc.). Also if you can’t find any properties, there’s something preventing compiling/indexing before you even get to this search request code. Comment out this search request code, see if you can build. Also, if you’re confident everything is OK and its still acting strange, empty the derived data folder and restart Xcode.

Comment: After the edit: this looks like you're missing an `@import MapKit;` in your source file. Also, are you sure you want this property to be weak?

Comment: Changed to strong and added import of MapKit. Still getting error retain error but now says property with retain (strong) attribute must be an object?

Comment: That generally means that the class name was not recognized. Perhaps you defined this property in the header? Move the `@import MapKit;` from the `.m` file to the `.h` file.

Answer (score 0):

Per apple documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearchrequest?language=objc

> If your app uses an MKLocalSearchCompleter object to implement auto-complete support for user-supplied search strings, initialize your search request using the search completion selected by the user. In that case, use the initWithCompletion: method to initialize your search request object instead of the init method. The completion object automatically provides the value for the naturalLanguageQuery property.

And use instance method https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearchrequest/3235757-initwithnaturallanguagequery?language=objc